# How to automatically update formatting in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have found multiple similar questions on the internet but I believe that each one is specific so here is my problem.

I am transfering data from my Access DB to my Excel sheet. The data that I am transferring is mainly contains mainly Time data. Because my Access columns are set to Date/Time - Long Time format, when I transfer the data to Excel, the values shown contain date as well of this kind: `00/01/1900 12:03:10`.

The thing is I don't want thee default date to appear as my column only contains hours. So in my VBA code, I am formatting the range automaticlly to `hh:mm:ss`.

The thing is this formatting works fine when I am debuggin (F8) and I can see my column directly in the correct format. But when I execute the code outright, the formatting does not apply. Here is the code:

```
Private Sub find_Click()
Dim conn As Object
Dim rs2 As Object
Dim strconn As String
Dim qry2 As String
Dim var2

Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.connection")
Set rs2 = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

strconn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data source = MyPath"

qry2 = "select * from taleA where mat=" & Val(Me.mat) & ";"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GTT").Range("A2:K10000").ClearContents

conn.Open (strconn)
rs2.Open qry2, conn

If rs2.EOF And rs2.BOF Then
   rs2.Close
   conn.Close
   Set rs2 = Nothing
   Set conn = Nothing
   Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   MsgBox "No result", vbOKOnly + vbInformation
   Exit Sub
End If

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GTT").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
Sheets(4).Activate
ActiveSheet.Columns("D:I").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss;@"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Sheets(1).Activate

rs2.Close
conn.Close
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set conn = Nothing

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Me.ListBox1.RowSource = "outputSource2"


End Sub
```

Thank You

Comment: Perhaps, change  Sheets(4).Activate  to  Sheets("GTT").Activate

Comment: I tried that already but didn't change much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this block

```
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GTT").Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
Sheets(4).Activate
ActiveSheet.Columns("D:I").Select
Selection.NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss;@"
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Sheets(1).Activate
```

to the following:

```
Dim gttSh As Worksheet 'Using this variable improves code maintenance/performance
Set gttSh = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("GTT")
gttSh.Range("a2").CopyFromRecordset rs2
gttSh.Columns("D:I").NumberFormat = "hh:mm:ss;@"
gttSh.Parent.Save 'This saves the sheet's workbook, whether it is active or not
```

The idea is to avoid using `.Select` and `.Activate`. Excel does not require that a range/sheet be activated or selected before modifying its values or formatting. It could be that `.Select` and `.Activate` are causing the difference in behaviour when you debug versus running the code outright.

I am not clear why the original code uses a mixture of `ThisWorkbook` and `ActiveWorkbook`. It might be better to just use `ActiveWorkbook` throughout (including in the new code above), especially if this code runs from a button, which will only be clicked on the active workbook. Also, using `ActiveWorkbook` allows you to move the code to PERSONAL.XLSB or to an add-in without breaking the code's functionality. You may want to check these links for more info on `ThisWorkbook` vs. `ActiveWorkbook`:

https://riptutorial.com/excel-vba/example/11878/activeworkbook-vs--thisworkbook

https://analystcave.com/vba-tip-day-activeworkbook-vs-thisworkbook/

Regarding the use of `.Select` and `.Activate`, the section "*Avoid Select and Activate Whenever Possible*" in this link may be of help (you will have to scroll down to the middle of the long page to get to the section) ...

http://www.excelcampus.com/vba/select-vs-activate-method/

Comment: Awesome! Glad to hear that!